# Angular/Ionic swap elements within *ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic2, material-design

I want to be able to create a list of items using `*ngFor` as follows..

*Text - Image*
**Image-Text**
*Text - Image*
**Image-Text**

[image]

```
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let item of items">
      <ion-col col-6 ">
        <ion-card ">
          <ion-card-content>{{item.name}}
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-6 >
        <ion-card>
          <img [src]="item.img"/>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

However, I am unsure how I could achieve this in a for loop.
Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply *flex-direction: row-reverse* when the index of the item is odd or even, your choice.

```
    <!--HTML-->
    <!--Track the index of each item and apply reverse class if its even or odd (which ever you prefer, just change the comparator)-->
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;" [class.reverse]="i%2 !== 0">
            <ion-col col-6>
                <ion-card>
                    <ion-card-content>{{item.name}}
                    </ion-card-content>
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-6>
                <ion-card>
                    <img [src]="item.img" />
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>

    <!--CSS-->
    .reverse { flex-direction: row-reverse; }
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working. However, the second index swaps but is not aligned side by side, instead it shows one above the other. Any solution for that?

Comment: play around with row-reverse and column-reverse

Comment: I see, I just had to use `row-reverse;` instead. Thank you very much